# Cleaning data from html

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-cleaning

I´m trying to clean a portion of data that I´m extracting through webscraping. The HTML code that contains the data is the following one:

```
<li class="price-was">
    $1,699.00
    <span class="price-was-data" style="display: none">1699.00</span>
</li>
```

To extract the data I´m using the following line of code:

```
price_products_before = product.findAll("li",{"class":"price-was"})
PriceBefore = price_products_before[0].text
```

I´m using this because the data is like:

```
'\r\n       $1,699.00\r\n            1699.00\n'
```

Using the following line of code I have managed to somehow clean it a bit but I´m still having twice the number.

```
PriceBefore = price_products_before[0].text.strip().replace("\r\n","")
```

I need to have just once 1699 without any space \r or \n.

Comment: You mean like this? PriceBefore = price_products_before[0].text.split()

Comment: Sorry, if you need 1699.00, then take it from the span instead of the LI

Comment: price_products_before = product.findAll("span",{"class":"price-was-data"})
PriceBefore = price_products_before[0].text

Comment: Doesn´t work...
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-a4319e640306> in <module>
     40     #Preu anterior
     41     preu_productes_abans = producte.findAll("span",{"class":"price-was-data"})
---> 42     PreusAbans = preu_productes_abans[0].text
     43 

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Perhaps the display none has something to do with it?

Comment: tbh I don´t know. This error gets displayed when I try to access more span tags... I guess is related to the span tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<li class="price-was">
    $1,699.00
    <span class="price-was-data" style="display: none">1699.00</span>
</li>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

try:
    print(soup.find("li", class_="price-was").next_element.strip())
except:
    print("Not Found")
```

Output:

```
$1,699.00
```

Comment: How can I store it in a variable? I need to export it into a .csv

Comment: Could you help me?

Comment: you were right! I´m idiot! Thank you so much! got it ;)